# Is there an easy way to get the soap message for the request and the soap message for the response, when invoking the web service?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, wsdl

I want to invoke a web service and i want to get the request and response objects as soap-messages.

```
var response = client.invoke(parameter);
```

I want to somehow get the message send and the message received.

Comment: For debugging reasons? Use a software like WireShark or the like.

Comment: No, i need it in my Application.

Comment: postman works like a charm and it's free too. I'm not affiliated, I'm just using it and I'm a c# dev: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector) helps you.

Comment: @Jabberwocky postman and SOAP? It works great with REST but SOAP? SoapUI

Comment: What i want to know is how to get an xml like the wcf-testclient has it

Comment: @BWA Works just fine with soap. Assuming what he asks is to just see the response and send a request. Postman is free SoapUI is paid. I use Postman for years now. Including for SOAP, not only REst

Comment: @Jabberwocky SoapUi has [free version](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html) enough for basic usage. SoapUI is more comfortable with SOAP than Postman. With Postman you must manualy create soap message, SopaUI generate it for you. But with boyh tools you can make SOAP call.

Comment: Not sure whether it is what you want , you could try messageLogging , it could log request message and response message, [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the MSDN article [WCF Extensibility – Message Inspectors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/18/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors/) from Carlos Figueira one option is using a MessageInspector.

Create an class that implements an [EndBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior?view=netframework-4.8) and [ClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). Buffer the request and reply message so you can use them later on. In this example I print them in the Console.

Here is the combined implementation:

```cs
// using System.ServiceModel.Description;
// using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
// using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
// using System.ServiceModel
public class InspectBehaviorAndnspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
{

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    public MessageBuffer RequestBuffer;
    public MessageBuffer ReplyBuffer;

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState){
       // messages are read only
       ReplyBuffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(2048);
       // so recreate the message after it was buffered
       reply = ReplyBuffer.CreateMessage();
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel){
       // messages are read only
       RequestBuffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(2048);
       // so recreate the message after it was buffered
       request = RequestBuffer.CreateMessage();
       return "42";
    }

    // not needed for client
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint sep) 
    {
    }
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint sep, BindingParameterCollection bpc)
    {
    }
}
```

Now on your `client` instance, assuming it derives from `ClientBase`, you can do:

```
var inspector = new InspectBehaviorAndnspector();
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(inspector);

// this is your call
var response = client.invoke(parameter);

// either do a ToString
Console.WriteLine(inspector.RequestBuffer.CreateMessage().ToString());
// or Write it with XmlWriter
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings {Indent =true})) {
    inspector.ReplyBuffer.CreateMessage().WriteMessage(xw);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

I have run this on an example with an Add service and this was my result:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ISelfHostTest/Add</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <x>3</x>
      <y>2</y>
    </Add>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <AddResult>5</AddResult>
    </AddResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: This would do if i implemented the service, but i don't impletment the services. Im only on the client's side that's why its tricky, still helpful.

Comment: @Danil.T this **is** client side.

Comment: I've tried implementing it, but its not working for me. I get a nullreference exception, even after copieng the code

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake on myside, i was invoking the method not directly on a client, but with reflection on a methondinfo object and my inspector wasn't added properly to the client. But i fixed it now, your solution works perfertly

Comment: do you know why i only get "datastream" as response? Is the buffersize to low?

Comment: @Danil.T That could be. Do you use the XmlWriter to output the message? The ToString variant will fallback easlily to only show the "datastream" message. The buffersize are fixed in my code example as 2048. You might want to try to make those bigger as well.

Comment: i used the toString() method, and ive already set the buffersize to int.max(). I will try it with the xmlwriter Edit :